# Javascript - Is it possible to make a function call itself after definition and then be referenced as a function elsewhere in scope

Tags: javascript

Consider the following:

```
 (function () {

     var _searchUsers = function () {
         console.log("Searching...");
     };

     var search = (function () {

         _searchUsers();

         this = function () {
              _searchUsers();
         }

     })();

     //Some onclick event handler
     function click () {
         search();
     } 
 })();
```

Is there a more concise way of achieving this feature in javascript? I want to declare a function and have it execute straight away and that's why I've made it an IIFE (self executing function) but I also want to reference that function elsewhere in scope later on the in the lifetime of the script, say when a user clicks a button and the "click" function is invoked above.

Example use-case:

I have a table of users, on page load I want to make an AJAX request to go and fetch the users immediately, I also want the user's to be able to load the users at a click of a button, let's say I have a search box which sends that text up to my API and returns user's who's name matches the given text.

The above snippet handles this requirement, I'm just wondering if there is a more concise method to achieve this, and i'm also just interested to see what people post as an answer.

Comment: Instead of the IIFE and `this` juggling, why don't you just call `_searchUsers();`, after declaration?

Comment: So basically you would like to have a function that does Search and call it from multiple places or is the function logic it self dependant on the input?

Comment: @Cerbrus For some reason I don't like doing that, i'm unsure why - perhaps my reasoning for that has no real substance and I should change my opinion. The reason behind this is that sometimes in my team other devs will place logic in between the function definition and the initial call, then the initial call gets "lost" in the code.

Comment: @Jester the function logic is literally just sending an AJAX request up to an API, any input given to the function would just get sent up to the API as request params

Comment: You can just declare a function and then call it the first time when page loads for example. And then you can attach it to some kind of event handler. Doesn't this suite your case?

Comment: If you don't know why you do something, rather stick to the standard way.

Comment: Use a clousure.

Comment: @MiquelAl.Vicens the code snippet above is using a closure lol.

Comment: Give the IIFE a name?

Comment: Not exactly. `_searchUsers` is been executed, not referenced.

Comment: @MiquelAl.Vicens Sorry I took your comment literally :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong in declaring a function and calling it separately. Actually this is a good practice that will lead you to a better code management. Don't try ninja tricks for no reason, people doing this should have strong arguments.

Comment: @procrastinator I guess my gripe is that once the codebase (that script file) gets large, it's just another line to read - If I can see at face-value that the function calls itself immediately and can be referenced elsewhere then I don't need to search for the initial call to the function, i.e. another developer could have moved it, either initially or by placing logic in-between the initial definition of the function and it's initial call. Totally agree with your sentiment though

Comment: `grep -r _searchUsers .` :-D

Comment: I was (almost) joking :-D I mean, trying to keep your code clean and easy to understand using self calling functions sounds like a contradiction. As you know, application architecture is a broad subject and we can't jump into it now, but I think you missed something smarter. Sticking to the standard way would probably lead you to a better solution, sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another option:

```
(function () {
    var _searchUsers;            // Declare the variable like you did already
    (_searchUsers = function (){ // Assign the function, and immediately call it.
        console.log("Searching...");
    })();

    //Some onclick event handler
    function click () {
        _searchUsers();
    }
})();
```

Comment: Awesome, I wasn't aware we could do that with JS (var_name = function(){}(); This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Mostly I see this being implemented like a named [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) function that returns it self after the execution. So that it can be used later on scope because it is a named function.

```
(function () {

     onClick(function MyFunction(){
          // logic code goes here
          return MyFunction;
     }());
})();
```